# How to return to index number

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write a program where the user can write their grocery item list, and then they can search whether they have wrote that item on the list or not. When they find if they have wrote down the item name it's suppose to return the index number and if they haven't wrote down the item name it's suppose to return -1. So far my code is able to find out if they have wrote down the item or not in Boolean expression.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GroceryStoreTest {
    // for the search item we need to create a method.

I wrote down a boolean method for the search item.

        public static boolean contains(String [] arr, String targetItem){
            for(String find : arr){
                if(targetItem.equals(find))
                    return true;

            }    return false ;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//lets create an array of string and add items list

        int list;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many items would you like to add to the list: ");
        list = input.nextInt();

        String[] items = new String[list];

        System.out.print("Write down the name of item without any space.\n(i.e.; Green Paper = GreenPaper)\n\nItems list: \n");


         int i;
        for (i = 0; i < list; i++) {
            System.out.printf((i+1 ) + ".");
            items[i] = input.next();// asks for next item name

        }

        // search in the items list

        String search = " ";
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the item to check if you have listed: " + search);
        search = input.next();
        //System.out.print(contains(items, String.valueOf(input)));
        System.out.print(contains(items, search));
        input.close();// it will stop taking the input
    }
}
```

Comment: You basically just need to replace the for-each loop in `contains()` with a loop that increments a counter, like the one you're using in `main()`.

Comment: After I erase some elements from the list, I want to print out the items again. What should I do? Should I introduce a new string and print out that?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you should just loop over the array and print each element that way.

Comment: I mean, how do I print out the new list after one item being erased?

Comment: Maybe you should ask an another question, with the relevant code included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just change your `contains` method to return an `int` instead?

```
public static int indexOf(String [] arr, String targetItem){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
        if(targetItem.equals(arr[i]))
            return i;

    }
    return -1 ;
}
```

Alternatively, you don't need to create your own `indexOf` method, you can just call `Arrays.asList(items).indexOf("valueSearch")` to get the index.

Another way to do this is to use an array list instead of an array. An `ArrayList` is basically an array without a fixed length. Your code will look like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

System.out.print("Write down the name of item without any space.\n(i.e.; Green Paper = GreenPaper)\n\nWrite "END" to finish entering items\n\nItems list: \n");


while(true) {
    String item = input.next();
    if (item.equals("END")) {
        break;
    }
    items.add(item);
}

// search in the items list

String search = " ";
System.out.print("Enter the name of the item to check if you have listed: " + search);
search = input.next();
System.out.print(items.indexOf(search));
input.close();// it will stop taking the input
```

Here is an example of how to remove all occurences of something from an array list:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add("Hello");
a.add("Hello");
while (a.contains("Hello")) {
    a.remove("Hello");
}
```

Comment: one for question, what if I want to erase an item from the list. Like lets say I wrote apple 2 times and when I erase apple ; then all the occurrences needs to be erased.

Comment: Generally you should declare using the _interface_ and instantiate with a particular _implementation_, so `List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();` (declaring a **List** not an **ArrayList**)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but there is another perspective: you should understand the difference between the for-each and the "counting-for" loops.

You got:

```
public static boolean contains(String [] arr, String targetItem){
  for(String find : arr){
      if(targetItem.equals(find))
        return true;
      }
   return false ;
}
```

Which is already pretty good. ( Maybe expect for the subtle thing that I would advise you to **always** put blocks in { braces }; as it is far too easy to get things wrong in order to save that little bit of typing. )

But in general, that code is OK. One should actually *prefer* this style of looping. Because that construct **really** improves readability by making you "read less".

But in your case: you need that index. So the for-each loop doesn't give you what you need. Thus - this is a case where an old school counter loop is better:

```
for (int i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
... and now i is the index you are looking for; thus the value to return

or -1 in the end if nothing matched
```

Answer (score 0):

through a cycle, comparing the values with the value adding looking toLoweCase method to avoid problems with case sensitive

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < items.length ; i++) {
    if(targetItem.toLowerCase().equals(items[i].toLowerCase()))
        System.out.println("Index " + i);
}
```

or using the [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class can be done as follows

```
 System.out.println(Arrays.asList(items).indexOf("valueSearch"));
```